Avy snipe-repeated command execution. Replacement only of the current candidate or jump further
Good day, I am using doom-emacs on Mac OS. I want to implement a new feature, using avy commands, but without the letter selection, but an immediate jump. Much like evil snipe command.
Instead of typing a letter and when selecting from the suggestions one would immediately jump to the first suggestion and then repeat the command.
The obvious advantage would be not to have type in multiple characters to get the first candidate.
In particular I would be interested in being able to replace ONLY the current selection, that is, if I jump to the next spot, the previous gets restored and only current selection gets modified (deleted for example).
Here is the current substitute below command I am using. I want it to behave in the evil-snipe repeat way:
(evil-define-operator my/avy-substitute-below (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Change a word."
  :motion evil-forward-word-end
;; Markers R x c y are important so the operator respects the count
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>"
               )

(evil-avy-goto-word-1-below )

    (set-mark (point))
(if (eq count 'nil)
(setq count 1)
)

(print "The count is" )
(print count)

(er/expand-region count)
    (evil-change (mark) (point) )
)

Is there an easy way to implement this functionality?

I made the desired behaviour work (only somewhat different functionality, repeated-zap instead of replacing next candidate) with
(evil-define-operator my-zap-up-to (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Paste a line below."
  :motion nil
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")

  (prefix-command-preserve-state)
    (set-mark (point))

  (setq  prefix-arg (char-to-string (read-char "char:" t)))
(evil-snipe-f 1
(list (string-to-char prefix-arg))
        )

(evil-delete (mark) (point) 'block)
    (deactivate-mark)

  (universal-argument--mode)
)

and
(evil-define-motion my/zap-repeat (arg)
  :type line
  "Paste a line below."
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")

  (prefix-command-preserve-state)
  ;; (setq  prefix-arg "a")
(print "Prefix argument is" )
(print prefix-arg)


(setq input_char (string-to-char prefix-arg ))
    (set-mark (point))

(evil-snipe-f 1
(list input_char)
)

(evil-delete (mark) (point) 'block)
    (deactivate-mark)

)

The first command enters the mode. The second responds to the entered prefix character in the first command.
You declare the shortcut by
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-snipe-local-mode-map "$" 'my/zap-repeat)

for example.
Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this, but this one is working.
